# What does JSR mean

Tags: java, jsr

I am developing web application with Spring and Hibernate. While searching in Google about validation and some other spring stuff I came across these words. `JSR 303, JSR 330, JSR 310` etc. 
What is JSR actually? 
And what the numbers indicates associated with JSR?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Community_Process

Comment: http://www.google.com/

Comment: Did you search for them first? A search for "JSR 303" takes you straight to the home page for JSR 303, etc.

Comment: https://jcp.org/en/home/index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**JSR** stands for *Java Specification Request*.

You can read about all requests here: [all JSRs](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/all).

JSR 303 is about [Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/) for example.

Comment: @whomever downvoted: care to explain?

Comment: @AdamAroid - I tend to agree, specific question with a specific answer - don't see a reason to downvote here.